# Cannot enter Recovery mode in order to csrutil disable

Tags: recovery, gpu

I'm trying the GPU fix. I formatted and drive and installed Sierra onto the HD (not High Sierra because apparently the latest version has issues with this fix).

I can't enter recovery mode. Cmd + R brings me to internet recovery only. It did this before when I originally had High Sierra . So I installed regular Sierra on there and I still have the same problem. It brings me to internet recovery only. Holding option does not show a recovery drive.

Could it be an issue with how I formatted the drive? 
Here are some pics:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1M8S.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7cCE.jpg

Comment: Try making an installer usb and booting that!

Comment: I already did that. That is how I installed Sierra. The only thing I can think of is I need to erase the Base System partition but disk utility doesn't let me do that (I can connect the internal hd to my working macbook). I'm pretty sure the recovery hd should be part of the base system?

Comment: I don't understand. From within the OS installer USB, you should be able to open a Terminal and run csrutil disable. No recovery partition needed.

Comment: You can only run csrutil disable in recovery OS. It even says it if you type csrutil in terminal in the options screen for it. I tried it in single user mode, internet recovery but doesn't let me do it.

Comment: I don't have a problem installing an OS. But i need to enter recovery mode to disable csrutil as part of a process of making it so that my computer does not utilize the faulty nvidia graphics card that apple decided to have run at startup for some reason. You know for all the intense graphics being rendered at startup.

Comment: @BL1333 You can also run it from the Terminal within a bootable installer USB. I know because I've done it. I'm sorry if I wasn't clear initially! Boot the OS installer, but instead of actually doing an install, go to Applications ==> Terminal and run `csrutil disable` there. Have you actually tried this? And if so, what went wrong?